# Instance methods defined between a class and a certain ancestor of it

Tags: ruby, inheritance, subclass

Suppose class `A` is a descendant of class `B`. What is the best way to get the list (array of symbols, order insignificant) of all instance methods of `A` defined within `B`, i.e., instance methods of `A` that are defined on `B` or any of its descendant class? Example will be as follows. Where class hierarchy is as follows:

```
class C; def c; end end
class B < C; def b; end end
class D < B; def d; end end
class A < D; def a; end end
```

the instance methods of `A` within various classes would be:

```
A.instance_methods_within(Kernel) # =>  (Same as A.instance_methods)
A.instance_methods_within(C) # => [:a, :d, :b, :c]
A.instance_methods_within(B) # => [:a, :d, :b]
A.instance_methods_within(D) # => [:a, :d]
A.instance_methods_within(A) # => [:a]  (Same as A.instance_methods(false))
```

Comment: A.instance_methods - C.instance_methods

Comment: @AlokAnand That is wrong. Take time.

Comment: My answer will be posted shortly.

Comment: @sawa I am trying,.... :-)

Comment: I knew that you know the answer. :)

Comment: One question - Could you tell the philosophy of considering the instance methods of the receiver will be thrown when `Kernel` or `Object` ? Why you think that way ? It may help me to re-think..

Comment: @ArupRakshit That is the highest in the hierarchy. Any method defined must be defined by `Kernel` or lower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
class Class
  def instance_methods_within(klass)
    return self.instance_methods if klass == Object
    methods = []
    this = self
    while this != nil
      methods << this.instance_methods(false)
      break if this == klass
      this = this.superclass
    end

    return methods.flatten
  end
end

class C; def c; end end
class B < C; def b; end end
class D < B; def d; end end
class A < D; def a; end end

A.instance_methods_within(Object) # =>  (Same as A.instance_methods)
A.instance_methods_within(C) # => [:a, :d, :b, :c]
A.instance_methods_within(B) # => [:a, :d, :b]
A.instance_methods_within(D) # => [:a, :d]
A.instance_methods_within(A) # => [:a]  (Same as A.instance_methods(false))
```

I added the special case for `Object` as `Object.instance_methods(false)` yields `[]`, thus the loop traversing upwards would not work well in that case. Updated to define the `instance_methods_within` class as an instance method of `Class`.

Comment: Yes, this is close to what I was thinking. Good point regarding `Object`. It would be better if you define this not on `A` but as an instance method of `Class` class.

Comment: @sawa It is indeed nicer when put as instance method in the `Class` class, I will edit my answer to do that.

Comment: By the way, do you have any idea why `Object.instance_methods(false)` yields `[]`? Some methods are defined on `Kernel`, so they should not appear, but there should be methods defined on `Object`.

Comment: @sawa Apparently all those methods are defined in Kernel. According to the Object Ruby Doc: *Object mixes in the Kernel module, making the built-in kernel functions globally accessible. Although the instance methods of Object are defined by the Kernel module, we have chosen to document them here for clarity.* http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html

Comment: I see. Then there is no need of special consideration about `Object`. You would get all the methods when you give `Kernel` as the argument.

Comment: My description in the question was wrong about that Sorry.

Comment: I eventually ended up using my own answer, but thanks for the point about `Object`/`Kernel`.

Answer (score 4):

This is my own solution.

```
class Class
  def instance_methods_within klass
    ancestors
    .select{|k| k <= klass}
    .inject([]){|a, k| a.concat(k.instance_methods(false))}
    .uniq
  end
end
```

Suggested by Marc-André Lafortune:

```
class Class
  def instance_methods_within klass
    ancestors
    .select{|k| k <= klass}
    .flat_map{|k| k.instance_methods(false)}
    .uniq
  end
end
```

Comment: Is the `.uniq` required? `instance_methods(false)` does not include superclass methods, thus when is `uniq` used now?

Comment: If `A` has `foo` and `B` has `foo`, then only `A`'s `foo` should be counted.

Comment: Nice, @sawa.  I don't see how this can be improved upon (though I confess I don't understand the oblique reference to `flat_map`).  Note that `take_while` could be used in place of `select`.  I rather like the way that reads.  You probably noticed that I posted an erroneous solution that I subsequently deleted.  I thought it could be done with `instance_methods`, `instance_methods(false)`, and set-type operations on arrays.  After @Alok pointed out a problem (and brought attention to my lack of testing), I had another go at it, but ultimately concluded it was a dead end.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to present this:--

```
    class Class
      def instance_methods_within(klass = nil)
        imethods = instance_methods
        own_imethods = instance_methods(false)
        return imethods if [Object, Kernel, nil].include?(klass) || [BasicObject, nil].include?(klass.superclass)
        sc_imethods = klass.superclass.instance_methods
        own_imethods | (imethods - sc_imethods)
      end
    end
```

Comment: When `A` has `foo` and `B` has `foo`, your answer returns `[]`.

Comment: @sawa will modify in some time, going for Holi festival celebration.

Comment: @sawa I have modified the code, please do review. It won't throw wrong array now, I guess.